# Append radio button using JQuery vs HTML - Bootstrap formats the text differently

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using JQuery to add radio buttons to a form and I noticed that the button text is formatted bold (when compared to marking up a radio button in HTML, or text in general).

Note this behaviour does not occur when I comment out the Bootstrap library.

How can I force the text to remain unformatted?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:background-color="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div>Normal text</div>
        <form id="myJSForm" ></form>
        <form id="myNormalForm">
            <input type="radio">myNormalForm</input>
        </form>
    </body>

    <script>
        var myRadioButton = $('<input>',{
            type: 'radio',
            name: 'myRadio',
            value: 'myRadio'
        });

        $('<label>', {
            insertAfter:'#myJSForm',
            append: [myRadioButton, 'myJSForm']
        });
    </script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change css of label as :

`label { font-weight:400!important; }`

Answer (score 0):

Another way to insert `input` element

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:background-color="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div>Normal text</div>
        <form id="myJSForm" ></form>
        <form id="myNormalForm">
            <input type="radio">myNormalForm</input>
        </form>
    </body>

    <script>
        var myRadioButton = '<input type="radio">myJSForm</input>'

        $('#myJSForm').append(myRadioButton);
    </script>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to do it using the "create an element + specify attributes" method? the code reads much easier